Extracting datetime column from PDF document
I am trying to extract data from PDF documents in R using "str_extract_all" function. I am trying to look for a date time field, which is displayed in the document in the below format:
Est Date
14-Apr-1988 11:59:49

I am currently using the below code and getting null as the output
Est_date<-str_extract_all(pdf_text,"Est Date +\\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3,}-\\d{4}")

How to resolve this issue any help?
My code:
Est_date<-str_extract_all(pdf_text,"Est Date +\\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3,}-\\d{4}")
Output:
[[1]]
character(0)

I am expecting the date value as:
14-Apr-1988 11:59:49

You are trying to match a pattern across multiple lines. See this

I am assuming that you have validated that pdf_text contains the text string (and only the text string) you give at the top of your post.
There are various ways to parse a datetime from a string. Two options:

Using anytime::anytime

txt <- "Est Date
14-Apr-1988 11:59:49"

anytime(stringr::str_remove(txt, "Est Date\\s"))
# [1] "1988-04-14 11:59:49 AEST"

Explanation: Remove the first line of txt (str_remove(txt, "Est Date\\s")) and let anytime figure out the format.

Using readr::parse_datetime

readr::parse_datetime(
    stringr::str_remove(txt, "Est Date\\s"),
    format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
#[1] "1988-04-14 11:59:49 UTC"

Explanation: Again, remove the first line of txt and the use readr::parse_datetime with a specific format argument to parse the datetime string.

Note how anytime and readr::parse_datetime assume different timezones. anytime will use the timezone from your locale; readr::parse_datetime assumes UTC.

Very useful this anytime: thanks for the tip!

This solution look up for a pattern at the beginning of a line in a multiline context.
library(tidyverse) # stringr | lubridate

# toy data
txt <- "Est Date
14-Apr-1988 11:59:49"

# With a pattern helper you can make changes easier
# (?m) Multiline
# ^ Beginning of the line
my_pattern <- "(?m)^\\d{1,2}-\\D{3}-\\d{4}\\s(\\d{2}:?){3}"

my_data <- txt %>% 
  str_extract(my_pattern) %>% # or `str_extract_all` maybe
  dmy_hms()

Output:
> my_data
[1] "1988-04-14 11:59:49 UTC"

you can define the timezone with lubridate::force_tz:
> my_tz <- sample(OlsonNames(), 1)
> my_tz
[1] "Europe/Stockholm"
> force_tz(my_data, tzone = my_tz)
[1] "1988-04-14 11:59:49 CEST"

Created on 2024-05-19 with reprex v2.1.0
